# Tempvars resetting to null when multithreading

Tags: multithreading, vba, ms-access

I have a function that I use to multithread some Access VBA routines. It does this by writing a vb script which saves a copy of the main Access database then opens it in another instance of access. when open it runs a defined routine specified in the vb script. this works well but I have some routines where I need to pass variables to them from the main function. I was intending to use Tempvars to do this.

the main function sets up the tempvar (complete with initial values), but when the new access instance goes to read it the tempvar has been set to null. I have no idea why this is happening. It does not error when it refers to the tempvar, so Im assuming that it can see it. but I cann't see the tempvars objects in the locals window anyway. is there a way to monitor the tempvar objects?

I have used tempvars in the past in a similar capacity successfully. the main difference is the new new instance writes to the tempvar and the main function reads them. the issue that Im having is the main function writing to them and the new instance reads them (which is opposite).

Comment: how do you expect anyone to help you when you gave next to no information.

Comment: sorry jsotola,I thought that I did. The question is really how do you pass tempvars from one access object to another

Answer (score 0):

TempVars are properties of the `Application` object, not the database. A new `Access.Application` will not have access to the TempVars set in an old one.

In my opinion, the better approach is to use forms, timers and COM to achieve this. That way you can pass variables from one `Access.Application` object to another (including, but not limited to TempVars)

A quick sample (I'm working on a more full approach to multithreading in Access)

Using a blank database with a single form, MTForm, which has a form module:
In MTForms form module:

```
Private strTask As String
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Application.Run strTask
    Application.Quit
End Sub
Public Property Let Task(Value As String)
    strTask = Value
End Property
```

And in a separate module:

```
Public Sub RunAsync(strFunction As String)
    Dim A As New Access.Application
    A.OpenCurrentDatabase Application.CurrentProject.FullName
    A.DoCmd.OpenForm "mtForm"
    A.Forms("mtForm").Task = strFunction
    A.Forms("mtForm").TimerInterval = 1
End Sub
```

Use: `RunAsync "MyFunction"` will run function `MyFunction` asynchronously on a separate `Access.Application` instance of the same database, that quits once execution is done (note that you can't have an exclusive lock on the database, else this will fail).

This can be easily adapted to add parameters, pass values from one thread to another, etc.

Comment: thanks Erik, I think that was kind of what I was trying to do, but unsuccessfully. You've given me some useful pointers to progress.